# Why is there no output on my second JButton?

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jpanel, jbutton

so i want my second JButton to print the reverse of the first one.
1-10 and 10-1.
But i cant figure out whats missing in my second button.
Also, how do i setback the value of the buttons so u can press them more than once?

```
package testgui1;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Testgui1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener //Alist visar vad
    //som görs när man utför ett klick
    {
        int i = 1;
        int two = 11;
        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();//Ny panelen
        JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();
        JButton mybutton = new JButton("1-10");
        JButton mybutton2 = new JButton("10-1");
        Testgui1()
        {
            super("Meny");
            setSize(200,200);//Storlek på frame
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//stänger ner rutan vid X
            Container con = this.getContentPane();//ärver mainframe
            con.add(mypanel); 
            mybutton.addActionListener(this);
            mybutton2.addActionListener(this);
            mypanel.add(myLabel); 
            mypanel.add(mybutton);
            mypanel.add(mybutton2);
            setVisible(true);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {  
           Object source = event.getSource();
            if (source == mybutton)
           {
            StringBuilder usual = new StringBuilder();
            while(i < 11) {
            usual.append(" ").append(i);
                i++;
    }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, usual, "1-10", 
                 JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                     setVisible(true);
         {
         if (source == mybutton2)
            {
        StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(); 
            while (two > 0) {
            reverse.append("").append(two);
            two--;
    }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,usual,"10-1",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    setVisible(true);
    }}}}
      public static void main(String[] args) {new Testgui1();}
    }
```

Comment: What results do you get? Did you step through your code with a debugger to check what it actually does?

Comment: It would be of great benefit to you and everyone else if you would properly indent your code. Many modern editors will have some form or another of auto-indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were Two problems:

1)For `mybutton2` you were using `usual` should be `reverse`.

2)Even after that,the braces after :

```
    if (source == mybutton)
       {
```

were not correctly matched,so,nothing was displayable on `mybutton2` click.

Corrected code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Testgui1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener //Alist visar vad
//som görs när man utför ett klick
{
    int i = 1;
    int two = 11;
    JLabel myLabel = new JLabel();//Ny panelen
    JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();
    JButton mybutton = new JButton("1-10");
    JButton mybutton2 = new JButton("10-1");
    Testgui1()
    {
        super("Meny");
        setSize(200,200);//Storlek på frame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//stänger ner rutan vid X
        Container con = this.getContentPane();//ärver mainframe
        con.add(mypanel);
        mybutton.addActionListener(this);
        mybutton2.addActionListener(this);
        mypanel.add(myLabel);
        mypanel.add(mybutton);
        mypanel.add(mybutton2);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
       Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == mybutton)
       {
        StringBuilder usual = new StringBuilder();
        while(i < 11) {
        usual.append(" ").append(i);
            i++;
                     }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, usual, "1-10",
             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                 setVisible(true);}
     {
     if (source == mybutton2)
        {
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();
        while (two > 0) {
        reverse.append(" ").append(two);
        two--;
}
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,reverse,"10-1",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                setVisible(true);
}}}
  public static void main(String[] args) {new Testgui1();}
}
```

**UPDATE:** As requested to improve the given block of code:

Just make your variables `i` and `two` initialize after every button click:

```
  if (source == mybutton)
       {
        StringBuilder usual = new StringBuilder();
        while(i < 11) {
        usual.append(" ").append(i);
            i++;
                     }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, usual, "1-10",
             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                 setVisible(true);
        i=1;//////////////////MAKE i=1 EVERYTIME////////////////
        }
     {
     if (source == mybutton2)
        {
    StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();
        while (two > 0) {
        reverse.append(" ").append(two);
        two--;
   }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,reverse,"10-1",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                setVisible(true);two=11;/////////////////MAKE two=11 EVERYTIME////
   }

     }
```

Comment: Thanks man!!
How do u reset the value so u can press the buttons and the loop will be shown again, without closing the JPanel?
like value = null;

Comment: @Krappington welcome :) i din't reset anything.the value will be shown only once.try clicking the same button twice,you won't get the output.

Comment: No i understand that. It was more of another question (or lack of english) to how i add some code that can show the output everytime u push the button.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using two different StringBuilders, but in both cases you only display `usual`.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,usual, ...
```

In the second invocation, use `reverse`.

Comment: It is so easy to overlook this kind of thing after you've been staring at the code for a while...